# Variation of Mertens Theorem

Tags: number-theory

Is there an analog of Mertens's Theorem on products of factors 1-1/q, in which the primes q are restricted to certain residue classes, such as 1 mod 4 ?

Comment: See [this paper](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/057.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Yes! In fact, a PNT-type asymptotic

$$\sum_{\substack{p \in \mathcal P\\p \leq x}} \log p = C \cdot x + o(x)$$
for any set of integers $\mathcal P$ implies
$$\sum_{\substack{p \in \mathcal P\\p \leq x}} \frac 1p = C \cdot \log \log x + o(\log \log x) \,.$$
You can show this implication using Abel's summation formula with the smooth weight $\frac1{p \log p}$. Exponentiating you get
$$\prod_{\substack{p \in \mathcal P\\p \leq x}} \left(1 + \frac 1p \right) = (\log x)^{C + o(1)} \,.$$

So for primes in arithmetic progressions, the Mertens type result follows from the PNT in arithmetic progressions. A better error term in the PNT gives you lower order terms and a better error term in the Mertens result.